# php syntax error on line 9

Tags: php, syntax

I have been staring at this for an hour now.  It says I have an 
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in line 9.

Could someone please look at this for me.  Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 function foo($a, $b)
{
   foreach(array_keys($a) as $i)
   {
      if(array_key_exists($i, $b){
          $result[$i] = $a[$i]*$b[$i];
      }else{
          $result[$i] = 0;
      }
   }
   foreach(array_keys($b) as $i)
   {
      if(not array_key_exists($i, $a){ //exists in b but not i a
          $result[$i] = 0;
      }
   }
   return $result
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 6):

You didn't close your parenthesis correctly:

```
if(array_key_exists($i, $b){
```

should be

```
if(array_key_exists($i, $b)){
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an `)` on this line:

```
if(array_key_exists($i, $b){
```

should be:

```
if(array_key_exists($i, $b)){
```

Answer (score 2):

Your missing a parenthesis in your first `if`:

```
if(array_key_exists($i, $b){
```

should be

```
if(array_key_exists($i, $b)){
```

Also, `not` is not valid operator (and a parenthesis is also missing). So

```
if(not array_key_exists($i, $a){
```

should be

```
if(! array_key_exists($i, $a)){
```

And finally you're missing a `;` in your return statement:

```
return $result;
```

I would advise you to use a PHP IDE such as Eclipse, which will point you syntax errors. We all do mistakes and finding a missing parenthesis in a text only editor can be very frustrating.